# How to fix '/usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so: file not recognized: File format not recognised'?

Tags: opencv, arm, cross-compiling

The code provided is my makefile. I am writing code for a UDP server capturing video and displaying it. I am trying to cross compile the code with OpenCV to work on the Intel Deo Nano Soc arm Linux platform. Any idea why the library files are unrecognized?

```
Server = UDPServer

LDFLAGS = -g3 -Wall
OPENCV = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-gnueabihf-

CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++

UDPServerMake: 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) UDPServer.cpp -o UDPServer $(OPENCV) 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(Server) *.a *.o *~
```

Comment: Does the so file exist anyway? if so, can you get some information with command like a 'file' or a 'objdump  -a' command? It might be a cup architecture problem with 32 bit or 64bit mismatch..

Comment: The so file does exist yes. How would I solve it if it is a cup architecture problem with 32 bit or 64bit mismatch?